# Delete <tr> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tablesorter">    
   <tbody id="fieldList">    
       <tr id="field_baf1034a_d9d1_a85f_3294_0de635d39c82">
           <td>Description</td>
           <td>Test Description</td>
           <td><a onclick="service.removeRow(field_baf1034a_d9d1_a85f_3294_0de635d39c82);" href="javascript:void(0);"> <i class="fa fa-delete"></i></a>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="field_85a21c73_da7c_3814_609e_0b743c8f014f">
          <td>Address</td>
          <td>Test Address</td>
          <td><a onclick="service.removeRow(field_85a21c73_da7c_3814_609e_0b743c8f014f);" href="javascript:void(0);"> <i class="fa fa-delete"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript code:

```
var service = {
removeRow:function(id){ 
        /* alert(id) == [object HTMLTableRowElement]*/
        $("#"+id).remove();
   }
}
```

Console Error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object
>   HTMLTableRowElement]

I want to delete table row, please help.

Comment: If removing was the only purpose, try `$(this).closest('tr').remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code by referencing the parent tr, not directly, but starting from the child td using jQuery [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

HTML:

```
    <td><a onclick="service.removeRow(this);" href="javascript:void(0);"> <i class="fa fa-delete"></i></a>

    </td>
```

Code:

```
var service = {
removeRow:function(el){ 
        $(el).closest('tr').remove();
   }
}
```

In this way you can avoid to hard code its id.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/keLnN/

Answer (score 10):

You are passing *identifiers* not *strings*.

Consequently, the horrible IE4ism that has somehow made it into HTML which causes every element with an id to create a global JS variable with the same ID is giving you the `<tr>` elements themselves.

When you `"#"+id` you convert the HTML Element object into a string, which is `[object HTMLTableRowElement]`

Put quotes around the IDs you are passing.

```
service.removeRow('field_baf1034a_d9d1_a85f_3294_0de635d39c82')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote the IDs when you have them in your html like that:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tablesorter">    
   <tbody id="fieldList">    
       <tr id="field_baf1034a_d9d1_a85f_3294_0de635d39c82">
           <td>Description</td>
           <td>Test Description</td>
           <td><a onclick="service.removeRow('field_baf1034a_d9d1_a85f_3294_0de635d39c82');" href="javascript:void(0);"> <i class="fa fa-delete"></i></a>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="field_85a21c73_da7c_3814_609e_0b743c8f014f">
          <td>Address</td>
          <td>Test Address</td>
          <td><a onclick="service.removeRow('field_85a21c73_da7c_3814_609e_0b743c8f014f');" href="javascript:void(0);"> <i class="fa fa-delete"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

or better yet, don't inline your event handlers and do it all in JS:

```
$('#fieldList a').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

which has the side effect of neater html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tablesorter">    
   <tbody id="fieldList">    
       <tr id="field_baf1034a_d9d1_a85f_3294_0de635d39c82">
           <td>Description</td>
           <td>Test Description</td>
           <td><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-delete"></i></a>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr id="field_85a21c73_da7c_3814_609e_0b743c8f014f">
          <td>Address</td>
          <td>Test Address</td>
          <td><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-delete"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the row, where is the button, the better way is to use "this", not hardcoded the Row's IDs, because if ID is different - you need to change the function.

Set all a-tags to be:

```
<a onclick="service.removeRow(this);" href="javascript:void(0);">
```

then, the function will be:

```
var service = {
removeRow:function(td){ 
        $(td).closest("tr").remove();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the mark up like this...

```
onclick="service.removeRow('field_85a21c73_da7c_3814_609e_0b743c8f014f');
```

hope it solves!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$('"#'+id+'"').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Create <a> tags like below

    <a class="removeRow" href="javascript:void(0);">

then in Jquery

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.removeRow').click(function(){
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove a child from its parent node so here is a small example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table id="table1" border="2">
<tr id="tr1" >
<td id="td1"><p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p></td>
<td id="td1"><p id="p2">This is another paragraph.</p></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
var parent=document.getElementById("table1");
var child = document.getElementById("tr1"); 

child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Actually here i have a table with a id of table1 as you can see...
in script i defined a variable with the name of child ...
now in last line `child.parentNode.removeChild(child);` `child` is the name of variable that we define earlier... after then `parentNode` will search for its parent node of child that is table and after then the `removeCHILD` will remove the `child`...

hope you understood! thanks